# Ubuntu Software Center / Update Manager not working - Could not open file

Tags: 11.04, software-center, update-manager

I'm having trouble with my Software Center, I'm running Natty Narwale and receive the following error when I try to open Update Manager.

> Could not initialize the package information
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package
>   information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and
>   include the following error message:
>
> 'E:Could not open file
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2011.04%20%5fNatty%20Narwhal%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20110427.1)_dists_natty_Release
>   - open (2: No such file or directory), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'

As I get similar issues in the Software Center I've tried removing it via the terminal but I get the same problem:

> Reading package lists... Error!
>   E: Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2011.04%20%5fNatty%20Narwhal%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20110427.1)_dists_natty_Release - open (2: No such file or directory)
>   E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Does anyone have any thoughts how I can resolve this?

Comment: I should add I've not reported this as a bug because I think it's much more likely I've updated something wrong as a linux noob than I've found a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. its caused by the status file parser not being able to open up the proper format that the status file is in. please report the bug.